# Go writing to socket - invalid argument

Tags: sockets, go, arguments

Im trying to write to a TCP socket in Go but only receive "invalid argument" with this code:

```
_, err := conn.Write([]byte("test"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

Comment: what about dial ?
http://golang.org/pkg/net/

Comment: please provide more context. What is `conn` and and how did you create it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample of what you want to do(maybe?), be aware that you should make a tcp server listen to the port `8999` first before run it

```
nc -l 8999     #or maybe nc -l -p 8999
```

code:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
)

func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8999")
    conn.Write([]byte("test"))
}
```

If it's not your question, you should provide more information.

Comment: Slight correction: You don't supply `-p` and `-l` together with `nc` (its actually an error to do so). You just need `-l <port here>` for it to listen on a port.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thanks for remind, but  I found the behavior of nc (`netcat`) will be different due to different implement, may be because of bsd version and traditional version?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I have once come into to a situation that `nc -l 8999` will not work in my debian box, since then, I use `nc -l -p 8999` instead, I just check the [manual](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/nc/) of the bsd version, it says that using a `-p` is wrong, but I don't know what will go wrong. And I also find guys [complain](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/06/netcat-a-couple-of-useful-examples/#comment-19403) that`nc`will not work unless  given a `-p`, It will be very appreciate if you could clarify what will go wrong, and I highly doubt that the manual guy just want to scare us :-)